# Why the `flash[:warning]` message is not displayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to understand why the following code in a controller action doesn't properly display the `flash[:warning]` message even if I state a `<%= content_tag( :div, flash[:warning]) %>` in the `application.html.erb` file.

```
flash[:warning] = "Warning message!"

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :root }
end
```

**Why the `flash[:warning]` message is not displayed? How can I display that after redirection?**

*P.S. I*: I tryed to use `flash.keep[:warning]` but that didn't work.

---

**SOLUTION**

The problem is that I am redirecting two times in my controller actions.

---

*P.S. II*: Who voted down can at least give some reasons...

Comment: how does redirects works two times in same controller's action?

Comment: @sannankhalid - I redirect to a controller action which in turn redirects to another controller action.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you written this line in your layout/view? If not then write this code in your layout file

```
<%= flash[:warning] || flash[:notice] || flash[:alert] %>
```

Comment: No, I haven't. However, if I write your code it still doesn't work.

Comment: why you are showing notice or alert ? he is storing message with warning key.your solution has many bugs can display odd messages to user

Comment: @Backo  are you sure u r using application layout? If not then add layout 'application' on top of your controller and try again. in your application layout u still need to write <%= flash[:warning] %>

Comment: @Naveed do you know what is meant by '||' sign ? I guess not. :)

Comment: @sannankhalid - I solved the problem (read the question for more information).

Comment: @sannankhalid he is displaying warning to user if there is something wrong,but in your solution user might also see notice like "Post updated successfully" :) if there is no warning,lets not discuses me know meaning of || or not

Comment: 'Post updated successfully' well its a notice not a warning so it will be rendered in notice tag, don't mix up man. Lalla g jan daio

Answer (score 0):

flash.now[:key] will save flash message again key for one request try it

```
flash.now[:warning] ='message'
```

and then after redirection show warning message with

```
<%= flash.now[:warning] %>
```

Comment: Your code still doesn't work. *BTW*: Does the `flash.now` create a "transient" flash entry? (!)

Comment: I solved the problem (read the question for more information).